# How to avoid entering git password if I need to launch a job on randomly picked remote centos servers

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have to automate launching a job on a remote machine. Machine is randomly selected out of hundreds of servers.

The execution of my job requires cloning the source code from a private repository. I want to avoid entering password manually.

If it was few servers, I could've added RSA key generated from each servers. But in our case list of servers is long hence adding RSA key doesn't seem practical.

Can anyone suggest some solution to deal with this use case of git?

Thank You

Comment: You can skip having to deal with password by using ssh certificates.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "git password". Git does not do authentication of any kind. The authentication is a feature of the remote server. In fact it seems Git is irrelevant to the question.

Comment: You can use the same key on all the servers. Not good from a security standpoint, but without the context it's hard to say.

You can set up a CI/CD system that will package the job into the docker container image and then use `docker pull/docker run` on the servers. Docker also requires authentication though.

Comment: Hi @matt, I am not saying "git password" as a command or something. I thought it was intuitive that password is for a git repository. And I need to bypass the manual password entry while cloning the code from bitbucket. That's why I thought git was relevant. Sorry if the question didn't make sense.

Comment: @EugeneMorozov Single deploy (read-only) key for all servers.